# map with const keys but non const values?

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants

I have a situation, where I would like to have a map that does not allow to add/remove keys after initialization, but the values are allowed to change (thus I cannot simply make the map `const`). Ie

```
/*semi-const*/ map<int,int> myMap = initMap();

myMap[1] = 2;                  // NOT OK, because potentially adds a new key
myMap.at(1) = 2;               // OK, because works only if key is present
for (auto & element : myMap) {
    element.second = 0;        // OK, values may change
}
```

I could write my own wrapper for `std::map`, but I have the feeling that it is something not too uncommon, so I wonder if there is already an existing solution.

**Is there some standard idiom for a map that does not allow adding/removing keys, while the values may change?**

ps: I know that the title alone is a bit vague, because the keys are already const in a map, but I hope it is clear what I mean...

Comment: No, I don't think there is, anything semantically equivalent to your requirement you coerce out of `std::map` (with `const` and `mutable`) is unlikely to read well, `std::map` is simply not designed to be used like this

Comment: Such map would be a waste. You can create your own class using sorted `std::vector` or similar. Using map has a certain price, pay that price without benefits (ability to rebalance etc) seems to be unreasonable.

Answer (score 5):

Could you create a wrapper that contains the value that allows the value to be mutated when `const` and put that in the `map` instead? Something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Mutable {
    mutable T value;
public:
  const Mutable& operator=(const T& v) const { value = v; return *this; }
  T& get() const { return value; }  
};
```

Then your map can be of type

```
const std::map<int, Mutable<int>>
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I1YmJWPd45bJnaVZ).

Comment: looks promising, I will give it a try

Comment: If the value is returned by copying, what's the point of mutability? Other than that, great general direction. +1

Comment: A sure sign of the fact I don't use mutable fields a lot is the fact I missed its requirement for `operator=` to compile.

Comment: The issue I have with this solution is that there may be times when you have the mapped_type to actually result in a const.  By allowing it to be mutable, you allow changing the value of the mapped_type even after it has become const.  That said, I really like the idea of changing the mapped_type to suit the needs.  I tweaked the demo to simply disable the default destructor.  This will prevent indexed access of the map altogether.  https://wandbox.org/permlink/r2X5UmXff5slxYDa

Comment: @Andrew Clever, although it is debatable if that really meets OPs requirement for "a map that does not allow to add/remove keys after initialization" since you *can* add/remove keys after initialization.

Answer (score 3):

I usually regard this as a pitfall in C++ more than a feature, but, if it fits your application, you can just use pointer values.

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    using namespace std;
    const map<int, shared_ptr<int>> myMap = { {1, make_shared<int>(100)} };
    // *(myMap[1]) = 2;  // Does not compile
    *(myMap.at(1)) = 2;
    for (auto & element : myMap)
    {
        *(element.second) = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which is really just a simpler version of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43865687/1782792) (obviously you may choose between `shared_ptr` / `unique_ptr` as needed).

Answer (score 1):

Containers from the standard library are classes optimized for one usage that are expected to be used *as is* or included in higher level classes.

Here your requirement (keys fixed after initialization) is not covered by the standart library containers, so you will have to build your own implementation. As it will **not** be a `std::map`, you can just implement the operations you need, probably nothing more that `operator []`...

Comment: "C++ is not Java" how is that relevant here? I didnt write any Java since more than 10 years, so my expectations are not coming from there. However, now you raised my curiosity. How would you do that in Java?

Comment: The main difference is that the standard java containers are implementations of interfaces, and that the standard library even contains helpers to allow you to easily build custom implementations. It means that your implementations actually are `List` or `Map`, when in C++ no container interface exist in standard library, and containers are not meant to be further derived.

Comment: but c++ containers are templates which generally allow much greater flexibility than an interface based design, so I dont get your point.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. This would actually be impossible to do correctly in Java. If you implement `Map` you have to provide `put`, and then the program would always compile; the best you can do is raise exceptions at runtime. In C++ you can have compile-time checks and still be within STL, since algorithms are built around iterator concepts (forward iterator, etc.), not collection concepts.

Comment: @jdehesa: I didn't want to start a language war here. Design of both languages are quite different., and each has its own advantages. I just wanted to warn that design of C++ containers templates is very different from the one for java generic containers. Programmers with more experience in one language are often amazed at not founding the constructs they are used in the latter.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sure, I wasn't thinking of language wars either! (I'm even... _reasonably_ fond of Java). I just did not understand your point, but I think it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you simply want to disable the index access operator so that a user cannot accidentally add a default constructed item to the map.  My solution is inspired by Chris Drew's solution but has the added benefit of remaining const correct (i.e. not allowing changing values of the map when the map is const).

Essentially, by disabling default construction you remove the ability to invoke the index access operator provided by `std::map`.  The other methods will remain available since `std::map` is a class template and member functions won't be evaluated until they are invoked.  Hence, `std::map::at` will work fine but `std::map::operator[]` will result in a compile-time error.

Inspired by Chris you can use a wrapper on the mapped_type to disable default construction.  I took his demo and tweaked it a bit to demonstrate how to disable default construction and used it with `std::map` rather than a `const std::map`.

```
template<typename T>
class RemoveDefaultConstruction {
   T value;
public:
   RemoveDefaultConstruction() = delete; // The magic is here
    RemoveDefaultConstruction(const RemoveDefaultConstruction &other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value) = default;
    RemoveDefaultConstruction(RemoveDefaultConstruction &&other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value) = default;
    RemoveDefaultConstruction(T &&t) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, decltype(std::forward<T>(t))>::value) :
    value{std::forward<T>(t)} {
    }

    RemoveDefaultConstruction& operator=(const RemoveDefaultConstruction &other) = default;
    RemoveDefaultConstruction& operator=(RemoveDefaultConstruction &&other) = default;
    RemoveDefaultConstruction& operator=(T &&other) { value = std::move(other); return *this; }
    RemoveDefaultConstruction& operator=(T const &other) { value = other; return *this; }

    T const &get() const { return value; } // Keep const correctness
    T &get() { return value; } // Keep const correctness
};

void update(std::map<int, RemoveDefaultConstruction<int>> &m, int k, int v) { m.at(k) = v; }
void update(std::map<int, RemoveDefaultConstruction<int>> const &m, int k, int v) {
   //m.at(k) = v; // ERROR: Cannot change a const value
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gt8SDSqdFohfCwPD)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here

1. Make the map const and use const_cast when changing something

   const std::map myMap;

   myMap[1] = 2; // NOT OK, because const map

   (const_cast&>(myMap)).at(1) = 2; // OK with const_cast
2. make an wrapper class or derive an custom map that has only read and update existing value methods

I don't think there is an built in way to make an map only with update value, and restrict and insert.

Comment: sorry, but that doesnt really help. The `const_cast` could be used in as well to add a new key, so I would still have to be careful whenever I touch the map which is exactly what I want to avoid

Comment: also it's **possibly Undefined Behavior**: `Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior.` taken from [const_cast on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)