Is there a way in C++ to pass a map where the structure is immutable but the values are mutable?
If a std::map is const, then its values are constant too. For example, I can't do this
void EditValue(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& m) {
  std::string& value = m.at("mykey");  // <-- compile error
  value.append("suffix");
}

But I could do this:
void EditValue(const std::map<std::string, std::string*>& m) {
  std::string* value = m.at("mykey");
  value->append("suffix");  // <-- this is fine
}

Is there no way to pass a non-pointer map and have only the values be mutable?

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43863978/580083 (the title is misleading)

I don't understand, if the structure is constant, how can you add items to it?

@ThomasMatthews I don't think OP wants to add items to the map.

std::map<std::string, std::string> and std::map<std::string, std::string*> are different types of maps, so the question is not so much how to pass it to a function but what map type to use, which is basically the same question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863978/map-with-const-keys-but-non-const-values (which has a very poor title btw)

You could use the frozen set of containers.  They allow you to update the value of the K,V pair.

you can wrap the key strings into a wrapper that is not default constructibe. This will not prevent adding elements completely, but its harder to do so accidentally


Is there no way to pass a non-pointer map and have only the values be mutable?

If the signature is fixed to be
void EditValue(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& m);

then, no, not without a const_cast inside the function, which is not under your control if I understand your comments correctly. It's also unsafe since you must not modify an object declared const and the function has no way of knowing if it is.

Otherwise, you could create a wrapper class template for this special scenario. Inside it, you'll keep a mutable instance of your map and provide accessors just like the normal std::map but with the exception that functions returning a T& can be const qualified - so you only need one at for example.
Example:
template <class Key, class T>
class map_mutable_values {
public:
    template <class K>
    T& at(const K& key) const { // const qualified but returns non-const T&
        return m_data.at(key);
    }

    template <class... Args>
    auto emplace(Args&&... args) {
        return m_data.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // add the rest of the member functions you want

private:
    mutable std::map<Key, T> m_data; // note: mutable
};

This would now work:
void EditValue(const map_mutable_values<std::string, std::string>& m) {
    std::string& value = m.at("mykey");  // <-- compiles fine
    value.append("suffix");

    // m.emplace("Hello", "world"); // error, m is const
}


why not drop the const on the function argument and instead of making the member mutable, provide no access to methods that insert elements. I dont think OP is dead set the const ref, but they only want to prevent adding elements (I might be wrong on that though)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I got the impression that OP wanted the values mutable while  not being able to add elements to the map.

I'll write an answer to show what I mean. Easier than trying to explain in english

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Ah... I think I understand where you are going with this. If I'm correct, one will not be able to add to the map even if it's taken by non-const ref - and perhaps that's what OP needs.

The problem with this solution is that it requires having the ability to change the input type that the function acts on. However, I don't own the code, so the function must ultimately act upon a std::map<std::string, std::string>.

@RobertMartin If the function only accepts a std::map<std::string, std::string> const& and you can't change it, then you are out of luck. In that case we can't come up with some nifty proxy object that will help I'm afraid. I updated my answer to answer your direct question.

To clarify, I may change the function signature, but it must act on a std::map<std::string, std::string>.

I could use std::map<std::string, std::string>& but the code will crash if any map iterators are invalidated in my function. I was hoping that the function signature could allow for the values to be modified but the structure of the map would not be changed, thus keeping iterators valid.

@RobertMartin Ok, I see. Then I strongly suggest going with 463035818_is_not_an_ai's answer since it's a simple wrapper to protect the function from performing anything you don't want it to be able to perform.

Inspired by this answer, I suggest to wrap the map into something that only grants access to the methods you need to modify the mapped values but not to methods that would allow to insert or erase elements.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename MAP>
class mapped_value_access {
    MAP& map;
public:
    mapped_value_access(MAP& map) : map(map) {}
    auto& at(const typename MAP::key_type& key) const {
        return map.at(key);
    }
    auto find(const typename MAP::key_type& key) const {
        return map.find(key);
    } 
    auto begin() const { return map.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return map.end(); }
};

template <typename MAP>
void bar(mapped_value_access<MAP> x) {
    x.at(1) = 42;
    auto it = x.find(123);
    if (it != x.end()) it->second = 42;
}


int main() {
    std::map<int,int> foo {{1,1},{2,2}};
    bar(mapped_value_access{foo});
}

Live Demo
I am somewhat hestitant to call it view because its more than that (but also less). Note that in contrast to the map_mutable_values this is just a shortlived wrapper. For example, it has no copy constructor, because it does not need one. You only use it when passing the map to a function that is not supposed to add or remove elements, but should be able to modify the mapped values.

You can use const_cast which won't be UB because the map's value type is not const, .... unless the map itself was initially declared const at construction, then it is UB.
void EditValue(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& m) {
  std::string& value = const_cast<std::string&>(m.at("mykey"));
  value.append("suffix");
}

note that a const& doesn't equal const, the compiler cannot ignore the fact that the const& object may be modified by an external factor (including casting away the const-ness of the reference), so the compiler must allow this code to work if the map was not originally const.
lastly for any compiler that implements std::map as an RB tree it will have a well-defined behavior even if the map was const, the reason this would be UB if the map was const is because the standard doesn't mandate that std::map be an RB tree, or that the RB tree won't be placed in a read-only memory.

Using const cast is a hack

@PepijnKramer Why? It "smells", but, AFAIK, casting away constness of a const reference to a non-const object is perfectly fine.

@DanielLangr If the map is constructed const then casting away const and changing it would be UB.

@TedLyngmo I think no one denies that.

@DanielLangr I mean, that's why it's a hack. The function EditValue has no way of knowing if m is constructed const or not.

@TedLyngmo yes that's exactly my point.

@TedLyngmo I agree, but if OP has the construction under control, then this might be a viable solution. Though a bit fragile for, e.g., future code maintenance. (The problem is that there are not many alternatives. One could use values being unique pointers, but this would come with memory/runtime overhead, which might be significant for someone.)

@DanielLangr And then the software goes into maintenance mode, someone else takes over and starts changing things.. So no, code like that is based on hidden assumptions and in my book not maintainable. In my book a const cast is breaking a contract (I ever only use it as second best option when calling legacy "C" api's, with const C++ data, and even then if data is small I copy const data to non const data and pass that onto "C"). Almost always it is a code smell and should be avoided.

Rather than casting away constness of the mapped value you could as well pass the whole map via non-const reference. Both relies on the programmer to do the right thing. Your solution causes UB when done wrong. Not adding elements when done wrong adds an element to the map. I know what I consider more dangerous ;)

@DanielLangr No offense intended I can see where you're coming from too ;)

@PepijnKramer note that because std::map is an RB tree even if it was const this code will still work with no UB .... but the standard doesn't mandate that the map be implemented as RB tree, only its complexity, which is why it is UB, because someone somewhere could figure out an implementation for the map that is not an RB tree and this code will fail to work if the object was const.

@AhmedAEK What says that the whole RB tree won't be put in read-only memory if the map is declared const? I'm not saying that any implementation does that, but they are not prevented from doing it either.

@TedLyngmo you do have a point there, someone could definitely invent an RB tree that could cause this code to be UB when the map is const.

If you can arrange some separate mutable storage for the values, you could instead use std::map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>.  That's equivalent to using a pointer for the value, except that it's syntactically transparent.
If you don't mind living on the edge, then you could create a "mutable value" wrapper that owns a value but is prepared to convert from const wrapper to non-const reference to value.  Beware that it's then the programmer's responsibility never to allow one to be constructed in read-only storage.
